# Ubuntu server, Django 1.11.4, gunicorn, nginx can not find css files

Tags: django, nginx, static, gunicorn

Got problem with static css. I already did collectstatic.

Css works fine if run

*./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000*

but can not be found if run

*gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 hotel_main.wsgi:application*

same situation with Dajango admin

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/opt/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        ('static', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'hotel_site/static'),),
        ('static', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),),
]
```

**Urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('hotel_site.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Nginx file**

```
upstream 78.155.199.17 {
    server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 78.155.199.17;
        return 301 78.155.199.17$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 78.155.199.17;
        location /static/ {
                root /opt/;
        }
        location /media/ {
                root /root/;
        }
        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
                $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass 78.155.199.17;
        }
}
```

**Project tree**

```
opt/
└─ static/
   ├─admin/
   ├─ckeditor/
   └─static/
     └─foundation/

root/
└─ ramn_hotel/
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently did as [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). It worked as it should.